# Keras: apply multiple filters to each feature map in CNN

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, cnn, convolutional-neural-network

I am new to Keras, and I want to do the following: take a 2D image, and apply four 2D convolution kernels to it, giving four 2D feature maps. I could accomplish this. But then I want to apply two  distinct 2D convolutions to each of those 4 maps, giving 8 feature maps. Is that possible?

Here's what I have so far:

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Conv2D

input_img = keras.Input(shape=(N_rows, N_cols, 1))
x = Conv2D(4, (3,3))(input_img)
```

But then I don't know how to apply 2 kernels to each of the 4 channels, so that I have eight 2D maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try Keras `DepthwiseConv2D layer`

> *Depthwise Separable convolutions consist of performing just the first step in a depthwise spatial convolution (which acts on each input channel separately). The depth_multiplier argument controls how many output channels are generated per input channel in the depthwise step.*

It will convolute each Channel separately. As shown in this depiction.
[image]
$\hspace{6cm}$<sup>*Image credit - [Blog by Chi-Feng Wang](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-basic-introduction-to-separable-convolutions-b99ec3102728)*</sup>

With `depth_multiplier` argument, you can add more Filetrs *i.e. more copy of the "triplet" shown in the depiction.*

> ***depth_multiplier:***
>
> *The number of depthwise convolution output channels for each input channel. The total number of depthwise convolution output channels will be equal to filters_in * depth_multiplier.*

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about these!